# How to setup authorization for ASP.NET Core Web App with Azure AD and AppRoles?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, authorization, asp.net-authorization, authorize-attribute

## How can I setup authorization for my Azure ASP.NET Core Web App MVC .NET 6 with Azure Active Directory using AppRoles?  If that is not the recommended approach, I welcome suggested approaches.

I have been following the msft learn documentation [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-authentication-authorization?toc=%2Faspnet%2Fcore%2Ftoc.json&bc=%2Faspnet%2Fcore%2Fbreadcrumb%2Ftoc.json&view=aspnetcore-6.0](azure app service authorization) as well as [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-add-app-roles-in-azure-ad-apps](azure ad how to add app roles), but haven't been able to get that to work when I deploy to the app service.  The authentication with Azure AD is working, and authorization works locally in Visual Studio, but not when deployed to the app service.  I receive access denied when navigating to a view with [Authorize(Role = "ContainerRestart")] when my user is assigned that role.

Here is most of the code in the program.cs file.

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(options =>
    {
        options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
        builder.Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options);
        options.Events.OnTokenValidated = async context =>
        {
            await Task.FromResult(0);
        };
        options.SaveTokens = true;
        options.TokenValidationParameters.RoleClaimType = ClaimTypes.Role;
    })
    .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(initialScopes)
    .AddMicrosoftGraph(builder.Configuration.GetSection("MicrosoftGraph"))
    .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();

builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.FallbackPolicy = options.DefaultPolicy;
});

builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews(options =>
{
    var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
        .Build();
    options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
});
builder.Services.AddHttpClient();

builder.Services.AddRazorPages()
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();

var app = builder.Build();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
```

In Azure AD I have created the AppRole "ContainerRestart" and assigned my user to that role. In the controller I have added [Authorize(Role = "ContainerRestart")].

Since the code works locally in Visual Studio, it leads me to beleive that there maybe a misconfiguration of the web app, but I am unable to figure out what I am missing.  Please help, thank you!

Comment: Have you check the official doc : [Protected web API: Verify scopes and app roles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-protected-web-api-verification-scope-app-roles?tabs=aspnetcore)

Comment: I did follow that documentation, but still seemed to be missing something.  I was able to get it to work now by using the following sample. 
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/tree/master/5-WebApp-AuthZ/5-1-Roles

Comment: Main differences:

services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
{
     // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
     options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
     options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.Unspecified;
     // Handling SameSite cookie according to https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/samesite?view=aspnetcore-3.1
     options.HandleSameSiteCookieCompatibility();
});

Comment: services.AddOptions();

// This is required to be instantiated before the OpenIdConnectOptions starts getting configured. By default, the claims mapping will map claim names in the old format to accommodate older SAML applications. 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role' instead of 'roles' // This flag ensures that the ClaimsIdentity claims collection will be built from the claims in the token
JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultMapInboundClaims = false;

Comment: Glad to hear you can solve the issue, you can summarize it as answer below, it might help more forum user who facing the same issue.